# django/python: to access defined constant by equivelent string

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views, django-1.5, django-settings

I have defined constant in django settings file like

```
LABEL_NAME = 'xyz'
```

And now I am having string `'LABEL_NAME'` with me and want to have its equivalent constant defined value i.e
`'xyz'`

I can able to access `'xyz'` value by `LABEL_NAME`. But I don't know how it can be accessed by string equivalent to defined constant.

I came from PHP background and worked with `codeIgniter` framework which provides the ability like this `@CONSTANT('LABEL_NAME')` to access equivalent defined constant value. Please let me know if we already have such kind of facility available in django/python. I could not get any help even after spending hour searching this problem.

I really appreciate your help of any kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `getattr()`.

```
from django.conf import settings

setting_name = "LABEL_NAME"
print(getattr(settings, setting_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from project import settings
print settings.LABEL_NAME
```

or

```
from project.settings import *
print LABEL_NAME
```

Comment: How I can able to access it if I have `'LABEL_NAME'` instead of `LABEL_NAME`. Does this make sense :)

Comment: You can't, 'LABEL_NAME' is a string. Why do you want to do that? Post your case in detail.

Comment: can't we have any method to convert string to equivalent global defined constant and fetch its value. I dont know if django/python have this feature available. But if it dont then I would like to know for what reason. Is this something that not be addressed or paid attention before. Or may be it just a stupid and foolish thing to do the way I want :).

Comment: You can do this `eval('LABEL_NAME')` and it will output the value of `LABEL_NAME`. In your case, there's no need to use `eval`.

Comment: Thanks @void. this helped :). But would you mind to explain how we can have it without using `eval` ?